# Has Curve25519 been replaced in NaCL library?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, libsodium

I am using NaCL library and I like it but I wonder what is required to replace Curve25519 with different, stronger curve if stronger encryption is needed.

I do understand that new library would be incompatible with NaCL.

Comment: This question is about the techniques used within a specific library, so I've moved it to StackOverflow rather than Cryptography.

Comment: Use curve448 if you want something stronger then curve25519.

Comment: I've tried searching for any other curve in the library. I see some mention of supporting P-256 (i.e. secp256r1) in the future, but nothing else. This leads me to believe that if you want to add support for other curves that you'll have to do it yourself. You may want to think of a way to add curves to the protocol, create a patch and present it to D. Bernstein. He's a very busy guy, but if you work things out I guess he'll be interested.

Comment: It is possible NaCL design requires cipher to be 256bit long. M-511 is 512bit. May be it would be easier to implement M-511 than curve448 as it is 512 bit and secp256r1 does not bring too many benefits. But will original Salsa20 and Poly1305 work with updated longer curve. I am not sure. That is why I was wondering if some did that or it is actually not possible and requires creation of absolutely new library.